# Open connection class in another class (PHP)

Tags: php, class

I have two classes :

**SQL Connection Class**

```
   class MysqlDB {

   protected $_mysql;
   protected $_where = array();
   protected $_query;
   protected $_paramTypeList;

public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db) {
      $this->_mysql = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');
   }

   public function query($query) 
   {
    //...................... }

   public function __destruct() {
        $this->_mysql->close();
   }
}
```

**User Class**

```
class cUser {

    private $_name;
    private $_email;
    private $_password;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_name = '';
        $this->_email = '';
        $this->_password = '';
    }

    public function getUser($username) {
        global $db;
        return $db->query("SELECT * FROM user where username='$username'");
    }


}


**index.php**
<?php
require_once('cMysqlDB.php');
require_once('cUser.php');

$db = new MysqlDB('host','username','password','db');
$user = new cUser();
$userData = $user->getUser('username');
print_r($userData);
?>
```

Totally works! Thanks to [Sabeen Malik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177766/sabeen-malik)

Comment: Is a user really a type of MysqlDB? Or should a user simply *use* the database connection class?

Comment: no sorry... I inheriting MysqlDB because I don't know how to open the connection when I want to get user data... I've update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not entirely sure why you are inheriting the `Users` from the `MySQL` class. But anyway, if you really need to do it that way.

Instead of

```
$this->_conn = new MysqlDB($host, $username, $password, $db);
```

do:

```
parent::__construct($host, $username, $password, $db);
```

You don't need the `$this->_conn` just use `$this->_mysql`

I believe the `MysqlDB` class would be in the singleton pattern. The User class would just use the methods of the MySQLDB class by talking to its object like :

`$results = MySQLDB::instance()->query(whatever);`

or something on those lines. Some people even use a global `$db` object and use that in their classes ( i am not condoning that though ) but there are several ways to go about this. I am not sure if you have chosen the right one.

Edit:
Using the global $db, you can get the user data like this:

```
class cUser {

    private $_name;
    private $_email;
    private $_password;

    public function getUser($username) {
        global $db;

        return $db->query(whatever);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. but if I don't inherit user from MySQL class, how could I call getUser function which need connection??

Comment: @Sabeen Malik it works!! thank you!! but there's an error with my destruct function. This is my first time use my connection class in another class.

Comment: @n00bi3 the destructor should be in the mysqldb class not the user class. the user class stays completely unaware of whats happening inside the db layer. So when the $db object is not needed, the destructor is called and it closes the db connection.

Comment: @n00bi3 You should create a new connection for that.

Comment: @Sabeen Malik do you mean new connection inside cUser class?? sorry, i'm totally confused working with this.

Comment: Sorry @n00bi3 , i meant create a new question :)